# Core data model problems

Tags: core-data, model

I'm trying to build a model for an app of events. For each event one of participants pay for all others and at the end of the event the participants pay back the original payer. I imagined this model like in the image attached but I don't know if can be the right way: I have some doubts about the participants who pay back. Is this a good way? Or I have missed something? [model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKarS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably have these entities:

1. Event
2. Organiser
3. Participant

It's possible that the organiser could actually simply be a relationship from event to participant entities, it depends on what different data it requires.

Each event has one organiser and multiple participants. The organiser pays everything and each participant has optionally paid back. The key to this is the relationships and the instances. In the real world a person could participate in multiple events, but I wouldn't allow that in this model, I'd require that the people were effectively duplicated so you can manage each event separately. Note that this could be done if you model the person separately from the participation.

So, you could end up with:

1. Event
2. Participant
3. Person

Event has a one-to-one organiser relationship to Participant and a one-to-many participants relationship too. Participant has a one-to-one relationship to Person. Participants record the amount paid. As each participant pays it could be reduced from the organiser payment.

Comment: HI thanks for you answer. the problem is that each event can have many "subvents" and each participants for each event can be the person who pay. for instance we have an event, with 4 participants. in this event, we have an sub-event1 ( paid by person1), subevent2 (paid by person1) and subevent3( paid by person3). At the end we will have, for each person a balance ( ex. person1 +20, person2 -15, person3 -15, person4 10). this is the model that I try to build

Comment: So keep what I said above but have another entity EventGroup or similar which groups those events. Instantiate new Participants for each Event (your sub events) but link each back to the same people (so participant to person is now a many-to-one relationship)

Comment: the EventGroup could have many subvents. the steps are:  create the EventGroup first; - create the participants to the EventGroup; - create the sub events to the EventGroup; create the organiser of subEvent; create the Person who pay back.

Comment: ? don't think as event and sub events, think as a group of related events